# Display HTML formatted text in a textbox and keep layout

Tags: c#, html, wpf, textbox

I have a html file which contains HTML formatted text. I want to display this text into a textbox in my c# wpf application. I'm using HTML Agility Pack to parse the text.

```
HtmlDocument HD = new HtmlDocument();

HD.LoadHtml(rangescenes.Text);

var root = HD.DocumentNode;
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var node in root.DescendantsAndSelf())
{
    if (!node.HasChildNodes)
    {
         string text = node.InnerText;
                 sb.AppendLine(text);
    }
}

Script = sb.ToString();
```

The result is that I get each line but I lose the layout. like padding and text-indent.

```
LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SITM AET   1

Lorem ipsum dolor sitm aet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Phasellus et neque rhoncus, accumsan augue sit amet.

NAME
blablalbal blablabla blablablab
bla blablablablablalb blablalba
```

and I want to get this:

```
1     LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SITM AET                            1

      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
      Phasellus et neque rhoncus, accumsan augue sit amet.

                           NAME
                blablalbal blablabla blablablab
                bla blablablablablalb blablalba
```

Is there a way to display this HTML file in a textbox like a webbrowser would display the HTML file with padding and text-indent?

Answer (score -1):

FIrst you need a hidden WebBrowser

```
 <WebBrowser Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="myWebBrowser" Visibility="hidden"
                    Width="480" Height="480" Margin="2 2 2 2" ></WebBrowser>
```

and load you html in code behind.

```
myWebBrowser.NavigateToString(sb.ToString());
```

after you need copy and paste the content to your textbox.

```
myWebBrowser.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", false, null);
myWebBrowser.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", false, null);
yourTextBox.Paste();
```

I hope it helps!!